# Ping server every 1 second infinitely till closed?

Tags: php

I'm wanting to set up a loop or maybe a page refresh that pings my server over and over again and tells me the milliseconds.

This is the code I'm using but not sure how to make it keep refreshing and giving me the response live. Can someone show me how to make it live so it constantly updates every 1 second or even every 2 or 3 seconds is fine also. Just need it to be live.

```
<?php

function pingDomain($domain){
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    // supress error messages with @
    $file      = @fsockopen($domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    $stoptime  = microtime(true);
    $status    = 0;

    if (!$file){
        $status = -1;  // Site is down
    }
    else{
        fclose($file);
        $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
        $status = floor($status);
    }
    return $status;
}
?>

Server Latency: <?php echo pingDomain('192.168.1.20'); ?> ms<br>
```

Edited with Paul's Code still no luck:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url='yourPage.php'" />
</head>
<body>
<?php

function pingDomain($domain){
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    // supress error messages with @
    $file      = @fsockopen($domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    $stoptime  = microtime(true);
    $status    = 0;

    if (!$file){
        $status = -1;  // Site is down
    }
    else{
        fclose($file);
        $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
        $status = floor($status);
    }
    return $status;
}
?>

Server Latency: <?php echo pingDomain('192.168.1.20'); ?> ms<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That would be an overkill + why re-invent the wheel? there are so many open source server monitoring solutions already available.

Comment: How it is overkill to monitor my server so I know anytime its down within seconds by just watching this script? I can access the script from my phone or anywhere else. I don't need some high tech script just something extremely simple like this one. If you know of one point me in a direction.

Comment: Example program is working correctly for me. What is your problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of:

1.Setting up refresh attribute in the page header

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url='yourPage.php'" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
//your php code here
?>
</body>
</html>
```

2.Use a crontab job to execute this command every second:

```
w3m http://yourhost/yourPage.php
```

I think the first solution is closer to what you need.

Comment: I just added that to the top of the php file and now it doesn't show anything on the page. The name of the php script is latency.php so I added that in the url='' section and now the page doesn't display anything at all.

Comment: Still getting nothing to the page. I took my exact code from the top up there and put it between your body tags and still not getting anything.

Comment: @FrostByte I updated it again, it's because the I didn't close the content tag properly so the whole page is broken. It works fine and I tested in my own server: http://sc2gogogo.no-ip.org/latency.php